# Java JDK silent installation with specified path

Tags: java, windows, installation, chef-infra, silent

I want to install in silent mode (in fact, using Chef) JDK in specified version.

My problem is, when I add INSTALLDIR parameter, Java JDK installation fails. Without it JDK will install in default directory (*C:/Program Files/Java/* or *C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/*).

I am running command

```
jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe /s INSTALLDIR="C:/java"
```

and also tried

```
jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe /s INSTALLDIR:"C:/java"
```

what makes Java installation show pop-up window with parameters I can use in MSI installer.

*C:/java/* path is existing directory.

Additionaly, I found this site:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html
where you can find specified parameters for JDK.

I want to use Chef resource windows-package for this installation

```
windows_package node['name']['JDK1.8'] do
    source                  node['source']['JDK1.8']
    installer_type          :custom
    action                  :install
    options                 '/s INSTALLDIR=C:/java2'
end
```

What makes output

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0, 42, 127], but received '1603'
---- Begin output of start "" /wait "D:\install\jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe" /s INSTALLDIR=C:/java & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of start "" /wait "D:\install\jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe" /s INSTALLDIR=C:/java & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% ----
Ran start "" /wait "D:\install\jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe" /s INSTALLDIR=C:/java & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% returned 1603
```

I should add I **don't want to install JRE** - my goal is to install JDK.

Is there any simple way to set up installation path for these installers in *silent mode*?

---

Specification:

- Chef 12.4.1
- Microsoft Windows 7
- Versions of JDK I would like to install: **6u35**, **7u79** and **8u45**.

---

I will appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `C:\Java` instead of `C:/Java` ?  Forward slashes aren't strictly legal in Windows paths, and sometimes they don't work.

Comment: Have you considered using the community cookbook? It reportedly supports windows: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java

Comment: @Harry Johnston, yes, I have tried both ways of slashes in path, no success though.

Comment: @Mark O'Connor, I will look into your solution tomorrow, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found solution for this problem.

Instead of using something like:

```
options     "/s INSTALLDIR=#{node['path']['jdk']}"
```

I had to use something like this:

```
options     "/v\"/qn INSTALLDIR=\\\"#{node['path']['JDK1.7'].gsub('/','\\')}\\\"\""
```

This way works for sure **JDK 6** and **7**. Here is full example for those who wonder, how to do it:

```
windows_package node['name']['JDK1.7']  do
    source                  node['source']['JDK1.7']
    action                  :install
    installer_type          :custom
    options                 "/v\"/qn INSTALLDIR=\\\"#{node['path']['JDK1.7'].gsub('/','\\')}\\\"\""
end
```

JDK 8 has problem though - using this line makes installation of JDK corrupt:

### [image: JDK installation fail]

For **JDK 8** worked fine this parameter:

```
options     "/s INSTALLDIR=\"#{node['path']['JDK1.8'].gsub('/','\\')}\""
```

Thanks for all your efforts!