# Install java through Chef-recipe

Tags: java, chef-infra

How to Install Sun java jdk installation 1.7  through Chef recipe?  I am newbie in this, Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Usually, you should show that you have at least tried something already and describe what the actual problem is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend following one of the guides, and coming here with questions. There are many great resources out there; maybe start with https://learn.chef.io/ and https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java#usage

Answer (score 4):

There is a cookbook for this, it is called the [java](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java) cookbook.

Comment: Sorry...I am using Linux System..I want to install on Linux Machine. I checked the from supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java , I downloaded into my Workstation. But , Not sure, How to do changes in recipe, attributes, Can you please help me?

Comment: @ChetanPatangade See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776899/can-the-java-cookbook-be-used-to-install-a-local-copy-of-oracle-java/

Answer (score 1):

You should have specified, in which system you want to install JDK - this varies on unix and Windows systems.

First of all, you can use cookbook `java`, which can be found [here](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java).

Additionaly, if you don't want to use any cookbooks, just install it through Chef resource.

In example, installing JDK on windows (requires `windows` cookbook):

```
windows_package 'Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 79'  do
        source              src
        action              :install
        installer_type      :custom
        options             '/v\"/qn INSTALLDIR=\\\"C:\\Java\\\"\"'
end
```

This will install JDK 7.79 in `C:/Java` directory.

Remember, that name of resource should be **the same** as package name in system - you can check them in *Control Panel* (Uninstalling programs).

If you want more informations about installing JDK silently, you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31749598/5176698) question.

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry...I am using Linux System..I want to install on Linux Machine. 

I checked the from https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java , I downloaded into my Workstation. 

But , Not sure, How to do changes in recipe, attributes, Can you please help me?

Comment: Ok, first of all, in the link of this cookbook you have examples on the bottom of page. Just do as they say - copy this to your recipe and run chef. I do not know if you are asking me `how to run Chef` or just `how to use this cookbook in my recipe`?

Comment: Thanks.. I have to follow below steps?

On My Workstation:-

1.knife cookbook create java
2. In /recipe/default.rb below code

# install jdk6 from Oracle
java_ark "jdk" do
    url 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u29-b11/jdk-6u29-linux-x64.bin'
    checksum  'a8603fa62045ce2164b26f7c04859cd548ffe0e33bfc979d9fa73df42e3b3365'
    app_home '/usr/local/java/default'
    bin_cmds ["java", "javac"]
    action :install
end

3. Save and exit.

4. Add recipe to node
5. Run Chef-client on Node

Is this rite?

Comment: You have to write your own cookbook and add dependency to their cookbook (of course download it and paste it to `cookbooks` directory). Then, in your recipe, just paste their resource (for example `java_ark "jdk" do`, depends on what type of JDK you want to install) and run Chef with your cookbook. You can read their documentation for more usage info - or just search in stackoverflow/Google - this cookbook is rather popular and have many results in searching.

Comment: Yeah, your steps are (more or less) logical, too. But make sure this URL for JDK .exe is valid - if not, you should change it ;)